# Are view engines and template engines the same thing?

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, facelets, templating, templating-engine

I'm curious as to what is the difference between the two, if there's any.

For example, .net Razor is a view engine/technology or a templating system? JSF's Facelets is a view engine or templating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order of how a typical html page is generated from a .cshtml file.

1. You create a Razor page (both html/c#)
2. You request a page (e.g. a View)
3. The Razor view engine creates a temporary .cs file to generate a .html page with the final output
4. The generated html is returned

**Therefore** this means that .net Razor is 2 components, a templating system but also a View generating engine.

I don't know too much about JSF Facelets but from the looks of its [jsf facelet wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facelets) page it is indeed a templating technology.